# How do I get the position of all elements in a HTML5 SVG element

Tags: jquery, html, svg, prototype

I'm creating a program similar to https://moqups.com/ and I can't figure out how to get the coordinates of all elements inside a SVG tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
var children = $('svg').children();

for(var i in children) {
    childLoop(children[i]);                 // Start with children because I don't think svg has
                                            // A getBBox() method (only groups, rects, text..etc)
}

function childLoop(obj) {
    alert($(obj).getBBox());                // Display the objects bounding box
                                            // Bounding boxes have .x, .y, 
                                            // .width, and .height properties
    for(var a in $(obj)[0].attributes) {
        alert(a + '=' + $(obj)[0].attributes[a]);
    }
    for(var i in $(obj).children()) {
        childLoop($(obj).children()[i]);    // Do it for the rest of the children
    }
}
```

Basically you need to select an element inside the svg object and call the `.getBBox()` method on it.

This will return an object with the following structure (used an object at position (0 ,0) with 100x100 dimensions for example):

```
.getBBox() : {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 100
        height: 100
  }
```

Comment: Some elements might have text and/or colors that go along with it, how would I retrieve those attributes ?

Comment: Take a look at my edit.  I think that might work... if you know all of the properties you could just use `$(obj).attr('fill')` for example